# How to enable a disabled text input field from one page to another

Tags: php, html

I'm am developing a project in php but my java is not good. I am trying to link two pages. The first page has a buttons including "Other" for donations which should work in a way that a user should click the button be redirected to the next page where the input text field for the amount should not be disabled.

I hope you are able to assist me because i read almost every post here about onclick events and other options and tried them but to no luck.

```html
//Code for the other button
<td  style="padding: 6px;">
  <span>
   <form action="getcreditcard.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo base64_encode(6); ?>" name="id">
   <button type="submit" id="donate" value="Other" class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 100%;">Other</button>
   </form>
  </span>
</td>   

//Code for the receiveing page getcreditcard.php
<
} else if (base64_decode($_POST['id']) == 6) {
    $p_price ='Add Amount Here.';
    $p_currency = 'USD';
    $p_name = 'Donation Option 5';
}
>
and 

 <div class="form-row">
    <label>
     <span>Amount (USD)</span>
       <input type="text" name="amount"placeholder="enter amount " value="$ <?php echo $p_price; ?>" disabled="true" required="true">
       </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. The PHP here is definitely invalid, and there is no javascript that I can see. Also remember, Javascript != java.

Comment: I Extracted Codes from the whole page so that you may see some of the path to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the javascript jquery prop() like this:

```
<!-- simple example: -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
Input:
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="enter amount " value="$ <?php echo $p_price; ?>" required>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#amount").prop("disabled", true);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: javascript jquery prop() helped be but i had to change the script from true to false and also remove the disabled property from the input. I had hoped that my form would accept values into a disabled input tag of type text. But when a user clicks the Other button it would then remove the disabled property and then allow the user to enter an amount.
At least its a working Code thank you for the assistance and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use *readonly* 
i hope this help you.

```
<input type="text" readonly value="<?php echo base64_encode(6); ?>" name="id">
```

Comment: I changed to readonly and it still isn't showing the results i am expecting.